# Narrow down files which names include date to specific months in r

Tags: r

I have thousands of .tif files which contain daily temperature data. The file names include the date in a format like this `tminYYYYMMDD.tif`, here is a sample:

```
tmin19810707.tif
tmin19810508.tif
tmin19810314.tif
tmin19810227.tif
```

I only need the data from June (06), July (07) and August (08) form all those years. How can I select and use for further processing only files that are from those months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substr` for a base R solution:

```r
x <- c("tmin19810707.tif", "tmin19810508.tif", "tmin19810314.tif",
       "tmin19810227.tif")
output <- x[substr(x, 9, 10) %in% c("06", "07", "08")]
output

[1] "tmin19810707.tif"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with a regular expression indicating the pattern:

```
grep("\\D+\\d{4}0[6-8]", x, value = TRUE)

[1] "tmin19810707.tif"
```

---

```
x<- c("tmin19810707.tif", "tmin19810508.tif", "tmin19810314.tif", "tmin19810227.tif")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time I'm coming across grep. If I wanted to select also years from 1981 until 1986 how would the grep change then? In my example above I was selecting months (and I would like to add a selection of years).

Comment: @JoannaOK ifyou need year 1981-1986 alone use `198[1-6]` if you need year 1981-1986 and month 06-08 `198[1-6]0[6-8]`

Answer (score 1):

stole the regex from the answer from @onyambu

```
list.files(path = "./mypath", pattern = "\\D+\\d{4}0[6-8].*\\.tif$")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer haha. Realized OP talked about files. They must be in a folder. Only `list.files` works +1 ;)

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time I'm coming across grep/regex. If I wanted to select also years from 1981 until 1986 how would the grep change then? In my example above I was selecting months (and I would like to add a selection of years)

Comment: @JoannaOK you would have to use the specific regular expression. eg for years between 1981-1986, use `grep('\\D198[1-6]', x, value = TRUE)` if you want to select the years 1981-1986 AND the months 06-08, then use `198[1-6]0[6-8]`

Comment: By analogy I wanted to try to play with the code and extend the range of years to 1981 - 1993 so i tried:  grep("\\D+\\19[85-90]0[6-8]",x, value = TRUE) but it produces an Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\D" What could be causing?

Comment: or I tried grep("\\D19[81-93]0[6-8]", x, value = TRUE) but the result is "empty".

Comment: @JoannaOK you should try experimenting with your regexes on a site like regex101.com, or similar. Than you'll see what it actually does. What you are trying to do will not work, sice a regex  sees everything as character, and not as numeric/integer, so you cannot set a numerical range like 81-95.... If you want to select years 1981-1991, you should trysomething like: `\\D+19(8[1-9]|9[0-1]).*\\.tif$`, see https://regex101.com/r/tvHQPy/1 (note that in R, you need to escape the \-character, so it will becomde \\ in your code